# Dynamic width with table-cell

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the width of `div.widget__stars` dynamic using `min-width` property . However the `min-width` property is ignored when I use `display: table-cell;`.

I've already tried `display: inline-block;` but it didn't work.

The red bar (`div.widget__bar`) can't have a fixed width either.

Here is my example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="widget-row">
    <div class="widget widget__stars">5 stars</div>
    <div class="widget widget__bar"></div>
    <div class="widget widget__percent">70%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container,
.widget-row {
  width: 100%;
}

.widget-row {
  display: table;
}
.widget {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.widget__bar {
  background: tomato;
}

.widget__stars {
  width: 48px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.widget__percent {
 width: 50px;
 padding-left: 5px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/unx38Lkb/)**

If you set the width of `.widget__stars` to `min-width: 48px;` the red bar disappears.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700);
 body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.widget-row {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.widget {} .widget__bar {
  background: tomato;
  flex: 1
}
.widget__stars {
  padding-right: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.widget__percent {
  width: 50px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget-row">
  <div class="widget widget__stars">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="widget widget__bar"></div>
  <div class="widget widget__percent">70%</div>
</div>


<div class="widget-row">
  <div class="widget widget__stars">5 Stars</div>
  <div class="widget widget__bar"></div>
  <div class="widget widget__percent">70%</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Paulie_D. I was searching for something similar on CSS Tricks but couldn't find it. I tried using white-space: nowrap; but it messed with the rest of the content. So your solution worked =)

Answer (score 1):

> If you set the width of `.widget__stars` to `min-width: 48px;` the red bar
>   disappears.
>
> Any ideas on how to fix this?

If you are going to give `.widget__stars` a `min-width`...

... you *also* have to give `.widget__bar` a `min-width` (or a `max-width`, or a `width`).

Otherwise, `.widget__stars` will obliterate `.widget__bar`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700);

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.container,
.widget-row {
  width: 100%;
}

.widget-row {
  display: table;
}
.widget {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.widget__bar {
  background: tomato;
}

.widget__stars {
  width: 48px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.widget__percent {
 width: 50px;
 padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="widget-row">
    <div class="widget widget__stars">5 stars or 6 star or 7 stars...just long text here</div>
    <div class="widget widget__bar"></div>
    <div class="widget widget__percent">70%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

try to add this:

```
.widget__stars {
  width: 48px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```